# Can I use a read-write root filesystem disk image as an OverlayFS upperdir?

Tags: linux, root-filesystem, overlayfs, union-mount

Is it possible to union-mount an existing disk image containing a root filesystem to the `upperdir` of an `overlayfs` mount for read-write access?

I'm trying to union-mount some old disk images to a `/tmp/` directory on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine using pre-existing scripts (originally written on Ubuntu 12.04 and ported to 14.04).

The old automation scripts used `overlayfs` to create and union-mount writable `ext2/3` disk images on top of `squashfs` images — something like this:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir lower upper union
losetup /dev/loop1 /tmp/image.sfs
losetup /dev/loop2 /tmp/image.ext2
mount -t squashfs -o ro /dev/loop1 /tmp/lower
mount -t ext2 -o rw /dev/loop2 /tmp/upper
mount -t overlayfs -o rw,lowerdir=/tmp/lower,upperdir=/tmp/upper overlayfs /tmp/union
```

They were last used on an 3.x kernel (likely pre-3.18), and that method doesn't seem to work anymore. Overlay now requires a `workdir` option—e.g.:

```
mount -t overlay -o rw,lowerdir=/tmp/lower,upperdir=/tmp/upper,workdir=/tmp/work overlay /tmp/union
```

**Q:** Is it possible to tweak the automation scripts to mount and use the existing images in a writable state on a 4.x kernel? Can I avoid reformulating them to contain something like `root` and `work` directories? In some cases that may break their use elsewhere.

Per the documentation, the `workdir` has to be an empty directory on the same filesystem as the `upperdir` to allow for atomic writes. That sounds to me like it is impossible to union-mount root filesystem images as read-write. The `workdir` would have to exist within the images (separate from their data directory) which isn't possible in a root filesystem image.

I've considered loading up stock Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM for a couple one-offs, but it's not a long term solution.

---

**Best Attempt So Far:**

The only solution I've come up with that avoids double-writing the same data to disk is to mount both images as `lowerdir` values, with `upperdir` and `workdir` directories sitting on a `tmpfs` mount. Then I can use `rsync` to copy the changes from the `tmpfs` location to the mounted `ext2/3` image after the automated writes are complete and the overlay union has been unmounted—i.e.:

```
mount -t overlay -o rw,lowerdir=/tmp/upper:/tmp/lower,upperdir=/tmp/tmpfs/root,workdir=/tmp/tmpfs/work overlay /tmp/union

...perform automated reads/writes...

umount /tmp/union

...rsync contents from /tmp/tmpfs/root to /tmp/upper...
```

It's strictly limited to available RAM, though, and it's an ugly hack to add to all of the automation scripts.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for the retitle to help with exposure, but I **do not** want to use overlayfs for my root filesystem. I'm trying to union-mount an overlay disk image (that contains root filesystem changes and whiteouts) to the `upperdir` position above a read-only `lowerdir` root filesystem image as a **temporary** mount under `/tmp/`. Effectively, the old automation scripts are remotely modifying offline user system images that are based on a shared disk image (conceptually similar to how Docker works). The new title may confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

Create an *additional level* of nesting in the image file:

```
mkdir   /tmp/upper/upper
mkdir   /tmp/upper/work
mount -t overlay -o rw,lowerdir=/tmp/lower,upperdir=/tmp/upper/upper,workdir=/tmp/upper/work overlay /tmp/union
```